# In CakePHP3 migrations (or Phinx), how to use utf8mb4 charset?

Tags: cakephp-3.x, phinx

Creating MySQL table or adding columns with CakePHP3 migrations, charset is set to UTF8.
Is there the way to set charset utf8mb4?

(and, i found this issue... https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/issues/74)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the collation when you call the `table()` function.

```
public function change() {
     $table = $this->table('FooBar',['collation'=>'utf8mb4_unicode_ci']);
     //.....
}
```

You can only set the collation type. The character set will be extracted from that collation string. There for the above will have a character set of "utf8mb4".